# what is the correct way to pass Bearer token in header section of my HTTP.Post in flutter

Tags: flutter

My Post API need a `customer_id` in body but also need a bearer token. I am passing it using following code

```
var myId="1005",
var token="my Token here"
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://haulers.tech/jashn/mobile/home/shoutouttype"),
      body: ({
         "customer_id":myId.toString,
         }),
      headers: ({
         "Authorisation": token.toString, //here I want to pass Bearer Token
         })
      );
```

This code return status code 401.

Comment: Make sure you spell it `authorization` - with a Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the word Bearer its must be Capitalized other ways it wont work, not sure whats the reason, but for flutter http calls make sure to capitalize that word like this

```
var response = await httpClient.post(
url, 
headers:{ 
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
},
body :{some body});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bearer tokens are usually sent preceded with `Bearer`  : the following key value pair:-

```
"Authorization": "Bearer {TOKEN}"
```

Should work.